# Replace command isn't working on console for Chrome 92.0

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to use replace command for my code but I'm getting two different output in two different version of chrome.

```
var v  = "[\"P10033592\",\"P10057941\"]"
v.replace (/\\/g,"")
```

The output should be :

```
v= "["P10033592","P10057941",]"
```

All I am trying to do is remove the backslashes from the array to JSON parse it.
P.S. - Although I have found an alternative solution I still wanted to know why it's like this. :)

---

This chrome shows the result I actually want. 
[This is the image of Chrome 83.0.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRK9x.png)

---

[The version of the above Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W95UP.png)

---

[The version I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxn2D.png)

The console output on the right is the output received in 90+ versions.

---

I just want to know :

- How come the same command works differently on two different versions of Chrome?
- Is the replace command deprecated? (I have also used the 'replaceAll' to check. It too shows the same result.)
- Also, I shifted this question from Stack Overflow to here, was that the right decision ? (I'm new to this ;))

---

P.S. - If you don't like the question, feel free to move forward. Thanks to all who help me with this in advance.:)

Comment: @user1686 , this is a response I get in JSON,and due to some circumstances it can't be changed.

Comment: @user1686 ,  I think you got something wrong, this is something I have to work with ( Sadly, I can't do much abt the response) so I decided to test it first on console and thus reached here.